# Why is hashset.exceptwith twice as fast iterating and checking !contains on the other collection?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, optimization

I was just doing a bit of optimizations and was baffled by this.

My original code looked something like this:

```
   HashSet<IExampleAble> alreadyProcessed;//a few million items
    void someSetRoutineSlower(HashSet<IExampleAble> exampleSet)
    {

        foreach (var item in exampleSet)
        {
            if (!alreadyProcessed.Contains(item))
            {
                // do Stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

This took about 1.2million ticks to process.

Then I tried the same with exceptwith:

```
 void someSetRoutineFaster(HashSet<IExampleAble> exampleSet)
    {
        exampleSet.ExceptWith(alreadyProcessed);//doesnt this have to check each item of it's collection against the other one, thus actually looping twice?
        foreach (var item in exampleSet)
        {
            // do Stuff
        }
    }
```

and it was running running at about 0.4mil-0.7mil ticks.

What kind of optimization is going on in exceptwith? Doesn't it also have to do a check over all items as I do in the first code-snippet?

Comment: @harold posted what looked like the correct answer, but he deleted it for some reason... `ExceptWith()` removes items from the collection so with each removed element it could get slightly faster when searching for the next element. With `.Contains()` the collection is never getting smaller so the search time per element doesn't decrease.

Comment: @MatthewWatson but exceptwith iterates the complete other collection. That one is magnitudes larger than exampleset. My first thought was to avoid iterating 'alreadyprocessed' and just do a containcheck while iterating exampleset once.  Using exampleset does exactly what I was trying to avoid but is faster

Comment: @MatthewWatson I just checked the sourceCode that was posted earlier... this would mean that simply iterating alreadyProcessed and calling exampleset.remove() on each item should give me the same speed as exampleset.exceptwith(alreadyprocessed))

Comment: Yes, it should. The code that was posted is the implementation of `HashSet<T>.ExceptWith()`, which you can check here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,3abdc44f36894d3c

Comment: @MatthewWatson I just tried it out and it is as fast as except with. Still don't understand why though

Comment: Can you share your perf test?

Comment: Are you getting hash collisions in IExampleAble?

Comment: @IvanStoev It also works if you make a custom empty class : iexampleable then just add a million new instances to already processed and pass alreadyprocessed.take(100000) to each test method and log the elapsed ticks

Comment: @user3488765 Only once I guess? Just to be sure not running the 1M tests on empty set since the first call is modifying the passed `exampleSet` :)

Comment: Please post executable code that includes a simple benchmark. Was this Release, x64 without debugger attached? The result, as stated, is impossible because alreadyProcessed is far bigger. So the benchmark is wrong in some way.

Comment: @user3488765 I've tried what you said and actually the "slower' method is much faster. Here is the test https://dotnetfiddle.net/u7KzJC. Build in release mode and run as exe outside the VS. Timings on my machine are Slow: 57,883 ticks Fast: 1,470,135 ticks

Answer (score 1):

According to Reference Source for [HashSet](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs) ExceptWith method in .NET Framework 4.7.2 looks like this:

```
public void ExceptWith(IEnumerable<T> other) {
        if (other == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("other");
        }
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

        // this is already the enpty set; return
        if (m_count == 0) {
            return;
        }

        // special case if other is this; a set minus itself is the empty set
        if (other == this) {
            Clear();
            return;
        }

        // remove every element in other from this
        foreach (T element in other) {
            Remove(element);
        }
    }
```

Only explicit optimizations in the method are for the special cases when a set is empty or "excepted" with itself.

Speed up you are experiencing probably comes from the difference between calling Contains(T) and iterating over all elements when the number of Contains(T) calls is comparable to the set size. On the face of it, it seems it should perform the same, old implementation called Contains(T) explicitly, new implementation performs the same kind of search in Remove(T). The difference is as the elements are being removed the set its internal structure becomes more sparse. This results in a statistically less items (slots as per source code notation) per bucket and finding an element becomes faster, if present then it's the first item in the bucket.

It all depends on the quality of hashing function for your objects. Ideally each object should be alone in it's bucket but most real hash functions would distribute million elements with collisions (multiple elements in the same bucket).